# ¿Como escapar caracteres en javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un script que agrega el contenido de una variable a una tabla y crea dinamicamente unos botones que deberian pasarle a una funcion un arreglo. pero este arreglo al tener caracteres especiales o espacios me genera conflicto.

A continuacion el script que genera la tabla con los botones. (Lo importante es la variable array y el llamado a la funcion editarSucursal en el Onclick del boton).

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

  $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "showStores.php",
                    data:{
                      'id':'helow'
                    },
                    success: function (mensaje) {
                   var data2=    JSON.parse(mensaje);

                        // tablamodificar
              var contenido=" <table class='table ' data-filtering='false' data-sorting='true' id='table2' style='text-align:center; vertical-align: text-top; border: solid; border-width: 1px; border-radius: 0;border-color: black;'>";
                                contenido+="<thead style='background: #064380;  color: white;'>";
                                contenido+="<tr>";
                                contenido+="<th data-breakpoints='' style='color: white;'>Nombre</th>";
                                contenido+="<th data-breakpoints='' style='color: white;'>Nombre Completo</th>";
                                contenido+="<th data-breakpoints='' style='color: white;'>Tipo de Documento</th>";
                                contenido+="<th data-breakpoints='' style='color: white;'>Numero de Documento</th>";
                                contenido+="<th data-breakpoints='' style='color: white;'>Email</th>";
                                contenido+="<th data-breakpoints='' style='color: white;'>Dirección</th>";
                                contenido+="<th data-breakpoints='' style='color: white;'>Altura</th>";
                                contenido+="<th data-breakpoints='' style='color: white;'>Piso</th>";
                                contenido+="<th data-breakpoints='' style='color: white;'>N° de telefono</th>";
                                contenido+="<th data-breakpoints='' style='color: white;'>Codigo postal</th>";
                                contenido+="<th data-breakpoints='' style='color: white;'>Ciudad </th>";
                                contenido+="<th data-breakpoints='' style='color: white;'>Provincia</th>";
                                contenido+="<th data-breakpoints='' style='color: white;'>Acción</th>";
                                contenido+="</tr>";
                                contenido+="</thead>";
                                contenido+="<tbody>";
            for (let index = 0; index < data2.length; index++) {
              contenido+="<tr>";
              contenido+="<td>"+data2[index].short_name+"</td>";
              contenido+="<td>"+data2[index].name+"</td>";
              contenido+="<td>"+data2[index].doc_type+"</td>";
              contenido+="<td>"+data2[index].doc_number+"</td>";
              contenido+="<td>"+data2[index].email+"</td>";
              contenido+="<td>"+data2[index].address+"</td>";
              contenido+="<td>"+data2[index].stree_number+"</td>";
              contenido+="<td>"+data2[index].floor+"</td>";
              contenido+="<td>"+data2[index].phone+"</td>";
              contenido+="<td>"+data2[index].zip_code+"</td>";
              contenido+="<td>"+data2[index].city+"</td>";
              contenido+="<td>"+data2[index].state+"</td>";
              var array = new Array(data2[index].short_name,data2[index].name,data2[index].doc_type,data2[index].doc_number,(data2[index].email),data2[index].address,data2[index].floor,data2[index].phone,data2[index].zip_code,data2[index].city,data2[index].state);
              // console.log(array);
              contenido+="<td> <button type='button' onclick='editarSucursal("+array+");' class='btn btn-sm btn-primary' style='color:#CBA92A    ;' href='#'  ><i class='fas fa-pencil-alt'></i></button> <button type='button'  class='btn btn-sm btn-primary' style='color:red;' href='#'  ><i class='fa fa-times'></i></button> </td>";




              contenido+="</tr>";

            }
              contenido+="</tbody>";
                                contenido+="</table>";

              $('#tablaStores').html(contenido);    


                  }
     });
 });
```

**Aca el script de la funcion que por ahora no hace nada pero deberia recibir el array**

```
  function editarSucursal(data){ //por ahora no hace nada}
```

**Y por ultimo el error que recibo en el navegador**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola @Augusto Vidal, por lo que veo , no has cerrado la llave del for.

Comment: hola @SebastiánLagosYañez , gracias por tu respuesta, no copie todo pero si la cierro justo despues de eso, el for lamentablemente no es el problema.

Comment: Para tener en cuenta el llamas dos veces a editarSucursal; una con el array y otra lo mandas vació.
Pero el erro si es por un ')' que no esta cerrada.

Comment: Hola Augusto. Si usas "\" al final de cada linea, puedes hacer un string multi linea y no tener que concatenar tantos `+=`. recuerda que tambien existen las plantillas de literales. Un saludo!

Comment: sisi gracias , pero son dos botones diferentes (el que no recibia el array no lo apretaba). De todos modos lo borre para no tener conflicto pero sigo con el mismo problema.

Comment: Podrias mostrar la function editarSucursal(data){}

Comment: @lois6b gracias por el dato, no lo sabia.

Comment: @MaxiGonzalez ahi agregue todo el codigo.

Comment: Es una mala práctica invocar funciones desde los elementos. Supongamos que la función `editarSucursal()` evoluciona, y en vez de recibir en parámetro la variable `array`, debe recibir otro parámetro más, o ningún parámetro... Te quiero ver hurgando entre todos tus archivos a verrrr en cuáles partes haces una llamada *in line*  a dicha función para modificarla y agregar ese cambio. Tienes que mantener el código lo más independiente posible, gestionando el `on click` mediante un *listener*  usando el id del elemento, así la función queda independiente del HTML y es más fácil mantener el código.

Comment: ... dicho eso, tampoco entiendo bien cuál es el problema. Yo quitaría esto del botón: `onclick='editarSucursal("+array+");'` y gestionaría los clicks del mismo mediante un listener (no será problemático, o incluso hasta más fácil recoger el valor del array desde el contexto de Javascript). Gestionar eventos in line es muchas veces problemático, confuso (de hecho, hay incoherencias en el código, como llamadas a `editarSucursal` con y sin parámetros) y *ensucia* un poco el HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás creando mal el array.

```
    var array = new Array(data2[index].short_name,data2[index].name,data2[index].doc_type,data2[index].doc_number,(data2[index].email),data2[index].address,data2[index].floor,data2[index].phone,data2[index].zip_code,data2[index].city,data2[index].state);
```

Tienes que escapar el código al html y recién allí colocarle el  `onclick='editarSucursal`

Prueba este ejemplo y dime como te fue ejemplo:.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "showStores.php",
                    data:{
                      'id':'helow'
                    },
                    success: function (mensaje) {
                   var data2=    JSON.parse(mensaje);

                        // tablamodificar
              var contenido=" <table class='table ' data-filtering='false' data-sorting='true' id='table2' style='text-align:center; vertical-align: text-top; border: solid; border-width: 1px; border-radius: 0;border-color: black;'>";
                                contenido+="<thead style='background: #064380;  color: white;'>";
                                contenido+="<tr>";
                                contenido+="<th data-breakpoints='' style='color: white;'>Nombre</th>";
                                contenido+="<th data-breakpoints='' style='color: white;'>Nombre Completo</th>";
                                contenido+="<th data-breakpoints='' style='color: white;'>Tipo de Documento</th>";
                                contenido+="<th data-breakpoints='' style='color: white;'>Numero de Documento</th>";
                                contenido+="<th data-breakpoints='' style='color: white;'>Email</th>";
                                contenido+="<th data-breakpoints='' style='color: white;'>Dirección</th>";
                                contenido+="<th data-breakpoints='' style='color: white;'>Altura</th>";
                                contenido+="<th data-breakpoints='' style='color: white;'>Piso</th>";
                                contenido+="<th data-breakpoints='' style='color: white;'>N° de telefono</th>";
                                contenido+="<th data-breakpoints='' style='color: white;'>Codigo postal</th>";
                                contenido+="<th data-breakpoints='' style='color: white;'>Ciudad </th>";
                                contenido+="<th data-breakpoints='' style='color: white;'>Provincia</th>";
                                contenido+="<th data-breakpoints='' style='color: white;'>Acción</th>";
                                contenido+="</tr>";
                                contenido+="</thead>";
                                contenido+="<tbody>";
            for (let index = 0; index < data2.length; index++) {
              contenido+="<tr id=\"tr_"+index+"\">";
              contenido+="<td>"+data2[index].short_name+"</td>";
              contenido+="<td>"+data2[index].name+"</td>";
              contenido+="<td>"+data2[index].doc_type+"</td>";
              contenido+="<td>"+data2[index].doc_number+"</td>";
              contenido+="<td>"+data2[index].email+"</td>";
              contenido+="<td>"+data2[index].address+"</td>";
              contenido+="<td>"+data2[index].stree_number+"</td>";
              contenido+="<td>"+data2[index].floor+"</td>";
              contenido+="<td>"+data2[index].phone+"</td>";
              contenido+="<td>"+data2[index].zip_code+"</td>";
              contenido+="<td>"+data2[index].city+"</td>";
              contenido+="<td>"+data2[index].state+"</td>";
              // console.log(array);
              contenido+="<td > <button id=\"editarSucursal_"+index+"\" type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-primary' style='color:#CBA92A    ;' href='#'  ><i class='fas fa-pencil-alt'></i></button> <button type='button'  class='btn btn-sm btn-primary' style='color:red;' href='#'  ><i class='fa fa-times'></i></button> </td>";
              contenido+="</tr>";

            }
              contenido+="</tbody>";
              contenido+="</table>";

              $('#tablaStores').html(contenido);    

            for (let index = 0; index < data2.length; index++) {            
                var array = new Array(data2[index].short_name,data2[index].name,data2[index].doc_type,data2[index].doc_number,(data2[index].email),data2[index].address,data2[index].floor,data2[index].phone,data2[index].zip_code,data2[index].city,data2[index].state);
            $("#editarSucursal_"+index).attr('onclick','editarSucursal('+array+')');

            }



                  }
     });
 });
```